# Затемнение окон Unity по нажатию кнопки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется кнопка и окно. При нажатии на кнопку окно меняет свою прозрачность. Как сделать так, чтобы изменение степени прозрачности было плавным?

```
public GameObject AlphaObj;
public Image AlphaImage;
private int AlphaCheck = 0;

void Update()
{
    AlphaImage = AlphaObj.GetComponent<Image>();

}

public void OpenClose()
{
    if (AlphaCheck == 0)
    {
        AlphaImage.color = new Color(AlphaImage.color.r, AlphaImage.color.g, AlphaImage.color.b, AlphaImage.color.a + 1.0f);

        AlphaCheck = 1;
    }

    else
    {
        AlphaImage.color = new Color(AlphaImage.color.r, AlphaImage.color.g, AlphaImage.color.b, AlphaImage.color.a - 1.0f);

        AlphaCheck = 0;
    }                
}
```

Как вариант, могу запихнуть смену прозрачности в Update с добавлением Time.deltaTime, а в OpenClose оставить смену проверочного значения. Но, быть может, есть вариант без перегрузки такой мелочью Update'а.

Answer (score 1):

1. код `AlphaImage = AlphaObj.GetComponent<Image>();` сильно влияет на производительность если делать это не в `Start()` или `Awake()`. И тем более это безсмысленно делать на каждом кадре в апдейте.
2. Для твоей задачи я советую использовать библиотеку LeanTween или ее аналоги вроде iTween. Там очень много полезных штук, в том числе и плавное изменение параметров. Например так:

   ```
    var time = 2.0f;
    var alphaVal = 0.0f;
    LeanTween.alpha(gameObject, alphaVal, time);
   ```

Comment: За твин +1, пора бы уже метку вводить имхо, вопросов в последнее время с ним довольно много.

Answer (score 0):

По мне так такие вещи лучше делать через стандартный аниматор. К нему пишите небольшой контроллер, который обновляет параметры по команде с кнопки и запускается анимация. Вот пример [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mz9xfDQ4FCk) на английском как делать.

Comment: Как по мне - слишком жирно для такой простой анимации

Comment: Зато процесс управления процессом обходится с минимумом кода. Контроллер анимации позволяет настроить стейт машину и править ее может дизайнер, не заморачиваясь тем что вы у себя в коде проставили. Я в своих приложениях таким способом делал анимацию появления окна, закрытия, и никто не мешает потом анимацию сделать более сложной и зрелищной, а то что прописано в коде  так просто уже не поправишь.

Comment: Вариант безусловно рабочий и хорошо расширяемый, но имхо - оверкил для такой задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [CanvasGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CanvasGroup.html) чтобы применить групповые действия над вашими окнами. Обращаетесь к компоненту `CanvasGroup.alpha` и вот вам и вся магия. Никаких сторонних библиотек не нужно иметь.